# How to find the pod that led to an error in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

If I look at my logs in GCP logs, I see for instance that I got a request that gave 500

```
  log_message: "Method: some_cloud_goo.Endpoint failed: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
```

I would like to quickly go to that pod and do a `kubectl logs` on it. But I did not find a way to do this.

I am fairly new to k8s and GKE, any way to traceback the pod that handled that request?

Comment: If you have configured '~/.kube/config' in you local machine, you could use `kubectl logs <pod_name>` to see the logs of each pod ([see here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#generate_kubeconfig_entry)). Where did you get this error msg ?

Comment: Thanks @KoopaKiller I get this error from the google cloud platforms logs (I am using GCP Endpoints)

The question is how do I get the `<pod_name>`? I have 10 replicas that could potentially have handled that request

Answer (score 2):

You could run command "kubectl get pods " on each node to check the status of all pods and could figure out accordingly by running for detail description of an error " kubectl describe pod pod-name"

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @Neelam answer, you can can get the pod names with the command `kubectl get pods -A` and log into all your pods to find the error.

Or, alternatively, you could deploy a custom monitoring system like [Elastic GKE Logging](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/elastic-gke-logging/README.md) available in GCP github [Click-to-deploy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy).

See [here](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elastic-gke-logging) to install from MarketPlace with few clicks.

It is a free alternative to have a complete monitoring system and you can filter your logs in Kibana dashboard after deployed.